# Error al hacer un if en Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

estoy haciendo un programa en Spring Boot con Java e hice una comparacion de dos String... Pero siempre me devuelve falso, aun siendo iguales.

```
public boolean GetCode(String user, String code){
    boolean r = false;
    for(int i = 0;i<cdes.size();i++){
        System.out.print(cdes.get(i).code.toString() + "\n" + code.toString());
        if(cdes.get(i).code == code){
            r = true;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Pero  siempre me devuelve false.
Esto es lo que me escribe en consola:

```
5603427230569370768938420845957870081281
5603427230569370768938420845957870081281
```

Comment: tal vez el problema de tu código sea que no definiste la variable `cdes`, ¿Por qué no lo revisas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String no es una variable simple, se le debe considerar como un objeto por lo que su contenido se guarda en una dirección de memoria y cuando haces comparación por "==" lo que se compara es esta dirección pero con "equals" lo que se compara es el contenido

```
String s1="5603427230569370768938420845957870081281";
String s2="5603427230569370768938420845957870081281";
String s3= new String("5603427230569370768938420845957870081281");

System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // true
System.out.println(s1.equals(s3)); // true 
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true
System.out.println(s1 == s3); // false
```

es un caso particular de String para evitar problemas usar siempre `equals` para la comparación de igualdad

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente en la condición:

```
if(cdes.get(i).code.equals(code))
```

No estoy seguro de si eso solucionará el problema, pero al menos cuando he desarrollado en Java, comparaba objetos mediante **.equals()**.

También puede ser porque 'cdes' no esté definida, como comenta Alain Torres, o que 'code' sea de tipo String y 'cdes' un array de tipo int. No hay mucha información sobre el resto de código.

Comment: En ese caso estoy suponiendo que tanto 'cdes.get(i).code' como 'code' son de tipo String. No sé si 'cdes' es un array de tipo int. Si es así, estarías comparando una variable de tipo int con otra de tipo String, dando error.